# Laravel sidebar set active tab when page are open

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

How can I set active selected tab and and also open the sub tab if the page I'm on is a sub page on my sidebar? For example if I open `Contractor Association` page, the `Users` tab should expand the highlight `Contractor Association` tab. Right now every time I open a new page the sidebar is will reset back

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('home')) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
            href="{{ route('dev-admin.home') }}">
            <i class="ni ni-tv-2"></i> {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'dev-admin.home') == 0) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
            href="#users" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="users">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">{{ __('Users') }}</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse {{ (request()->is('dev-admin/developer-admins*') ? 'show' : '' }}"
            id="users">
            <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('developer-admins')) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
                        href="{{ route('dev-admin.developer-admins.index') }}">
                        {{ __('Admins') }}
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('dev-admin/defect-types*')) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
                        href="{{ route('dev-admin.clerk-of-works.index') }}">
                        {{ __('Clerks of Work') }}
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('developer-admins')) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
                        href="{{ route('dev-admin.developer-contractor-associations.index') }}">
                        {{ __('Contractor Association') }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write the code like in side bar all the section

```
<li class="@if(Route::is('developer-admins')) {{ 'active' }} @endif"
<a href="{{ route('dev-admin.developer-admins.index') }}">
{{ __('Admins') }}
</a></li>
```

**and also you can use like**

```
<li class="{{ set_active(['login*']) }}">
    <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
</li>
<li class="{{ set_active(['register*']) }}">
    <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Signup</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt work unfortunately,even in different page, the `<li>` that I change to this format keep being on active

Comment: ohk so u can try using li tag

Answer (score 1):

I am using bellow code for many project which is used into production ready web app and api.

Add bellow line into html class attributes for highlighting active route.

```php
 {{ request()->is('dashboard/report') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

This is really handy for active class.

Answer (score 0):

So I fix it and also show/open tab for selected page by doing something like this, it appears the url I gave is incomplete, thanks everyone for the suggestion..

```
<div class="collapse {{ (request()->is('dev-admin/developer-admins*') || request()->is('dev-admin/clerks-of-works*') || request()->is('dev-admin/developer-contractor-associations*')) ? 'show' : '' }}"
    id="users">
    <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('dev-admin/developer-admins*')) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
                href="{{ route('dev-admin.developer-admins.index') }}">
                {{ __('Admins') }}
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('dev-admin/clerks-of-works*')) ? 'text-primary' : '' }}"
                href="{{ route('dev-admin.clerk-of-works.index') }}">
                {{ __('Clerks of Work') }}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```